# Angular js custom filter to array

Tags: angularjs

I want to apply custom filter to array ,here is the code ,i am newbie to angular js.Please help me figure out.How to apply custom filter to array,is it possible to apply custom filter to array
I want to make every 2nd letter of name capital using this filter but the filter is not being applied to x.name.

```
 <div  ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="my">

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td ng-click="orderbyme('name')">Name</td>
            <td ng-click="orderbyme('city')">City</td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myorder">
            <td>{{x.name | myformat}}</td>
            <td>{{x.city}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>


<script>
    var a=angular.module('myapp',[]);

     a.filter('myformat',function(){
        return function(x.name){
            var i,c,j,txt="";
            j=x.name;
            for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
                    c=j.[i];

                    if(i%2==0){
                    c = c.toUpperCase();
                    }

            txt=txt+c;
        }
        return txt;
        };
    });


    a.controller('my',function($scope){
        $scope.names=   [{name:'sarthak ',city:'nagpur'},
                         {name:'sayali ',city:'pune'},
                         {name:'amit ',city:'mumbai'},
                         {name:'komal ',city:'saoner'},
                         {name:'dhiraj ',city:'wardha'},
                         {name:'nikhil ',city:'yavatmal'},
                         {name:'sanjeev ',city:'delhi'},
                         {name:'bhavin ',city:'banglore'}

                        ]

        $scope.orderbyme=function(x){
            $scope.myorder=x;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a proper explanation of what you expect this filter to do along with a sample of expected results. You should probably take a few minutes to review [ask] and then [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39858558/edit) the question with proper details

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do is order when you click on the header of the table?
It is a little more explicit about what you want to do.